How to get the list of Stake Accounts given a Solana address, using the JSON RPC API?
When you stake funds in Solana, you create a new stake address. Is there a way to fetch the list of Stake Accounts given a Solana address, using the JSON RPC API?

It's certainly possible! Since the withdraw authority starts at index 44 of all stake accounts, you can use get_program_accounts with a memcmp filter on the authority, which exactly what the CLI is doing:
    let mut program_accounts_config = RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
        account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
            encoding: Some(solana_account_decoder::UiAccountEncoding::Base64),
            ..RpcAccountInfoConfig::default()
        },
        ..RpcProgramAccountsConfig::default()
    };

    let withdrawer_filter = RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_base58_encoded(
        44,
        withdraw_authority_pubkey.as_ref(),
    ));

    let filters = program_accounts_config.filters.get_or_insert(vec![]);
    filters.push(withdrawer_filter);

    let stake_accounts = rpc_client
        .get_program_accounts_with_config(&stake::program::id(), program_accounts_config)?;

Adapted from https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/4753a8aefaf5fdc2b40a579334bff04ada20a502/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L1807

Yes, but when the user unstakes, those addresses are pruned away and won't be returned anymore by the API call, am I right?

It depends, if the stake is just deactivated but the user hasn't withdrawn the SOL in the account, then it will appear. But if they've deactivated and withdrawn everything in the account, then the account will be deleted, so the account will not be returned.
